Movie about an aircraft carrier/ship that is sunk by the enemy. Sailors are being eaten and attacked by sharks
I'm trying to recall a movie that has aircraft carrier or ship that is struck by enemy action (presumably during World War 2). The surviving navy are being eaten/attacked by sharks.
The movie is definitely not USS Indianapolis: Men of Courage.
I thought it might be Unbroken, but don't think there is aircraft carrier. Could it be Dunkirk?

I can at the very least confirm that it is not Unbroken.

This seems too generic a description. We might assume the OP is talking about an American film, since all titles mentioned are American, but this needs to be explicated.

This could be this another, maybe lesser-known movie about the USS Indianapolis sinking:
"Mission of the Shark: The Saga of the U.S.S. Indianapolis" (1991)
The USS Indianapolis was a heavy cruiser and was sunk by a Japanese submarine in World War II. Hundreds of the ship's sailors survived the sinking, but a lot of them was eaten by sharks.




An excellent find. Even if this isn't what OP had in mind, I'll bet they'll enjoy this just as much!

Thank you. The first time I watched this movie was many years ago, and I very much liked it. I think it is a great movie, much better than the Nicolas Cage movie.
